# React-Router Bug

Tags: reactjs, routes, react-router, router

got a problem with react-routing. Tried to make tabs in profile page of my app, but i've got some problems with it...

It's working and bugging at the same time..

When i'm tapping on "dashboard" tab, the url looks like this: '/profile/dashboard', when i refresh the page, the content disappear from the screen, and just zooming:
[image]

[image]

Code:

```js
const App = () => {
 
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Switch>
        <Route path={'/profile'}
        render={(props) => (
          <ProfilePage {...props}/>
        )}/>
      </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}

const ProfilePage = () => {

  return (
    <>
      <ProfileHeader />
      <Sidebar />
      <div className="content">
        <Switch>
          <Route 
          path={'profile/dashboard'} 
          render={(props) => (
            <Dashboard {...props}/>
          )} />
          
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

const Sidebar = () => {

  return (
    <aside className="profile__aside">
      <nav className="profile__menu">
        <Link to="/profile/dashboard" className="profile__tab"><i className="fas fa-chart-line"></i><span className="profile__title">Dashboard</span></Link>
        <Link className="profile__tab"><i className="fas fa-flask"></i><span className="profile__title">Lab Results</span></Link>
        <Link className="profile__tab"><i className="fas fa-box"></i><span className="profile__title">Order</span></Link>
        <Link className="profile__tab"><i className="fas fa-cogs"></i><span className="profile__title">Settings</span></Link>
      </nav>
    </aside>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in the profile component change path to /dashboard from profile/dashboard, you can copy the ProfilePage component from below

```
 const ProfilePage = () => {
      return (
        <>
          <ProfileHeader />
          <Sidebar />
          <div className="content">
            <Switch>
              <Route 
              path={'/dashboard'} 
              render={(props) => (
                <Dashboard {...props}/>
              )} />
              
            </Switch>
          </div>
        </>
      );
   };
```